# How to find a down trend in MQL4 from coding

Tags: strategy-pattern, mql4, metatrader4, forex

[image]

I am writing an EA but I am beginner in MQL4. Please suggest me how could I identify a DOWN TREND or an UP TREND of moving average in my EA programmatically?

Please advise me as I have not so familiar with MQL4.

in the above image trend is not moving in up or down direction it moving in horizontal direction.

I want to make an EA using Heiken Ashi and MA. First in my code I want to identify weather its an up trend or down trend or a tread shown in the above image.

https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/136
on this link I found this:

> **2.1. Trend Detection Using Moving Average** 
>   Perhaps, the easiest way to detect a trend and its direction - using moving averages. One of
>   the first tools of technical analysis - moving average - is still used
>   in different variations and is the basis of most indicators. Traders
>   use both one moving average and a whole set of them, which sometimes
>   is called as "fan".
>
> Let's formulate a simple rule for one moving average: 
>   **Trend goes up** if at a given timeframe the closing price of bar is **above** moving average.
>   **Trend goes down** if at a given timeframe the closing price of bar is
>   **below** moving average.

If I identify trend like said above if price close above MA then its an up trend and if price close below MA then its a down trend that how could I identify that horizontal moving trend?

Please guide.

Comment: how would you explain that in plain language? If you are asking how to obtain MA value of a particular bar / time with some other indicator properties - please edit your question. If you would like to know about the ideas how MA could be employed to detect trend - Forex/Trading forums should help you, not SOF

Comment: so what is your question? You cannot get the closing price of bar? or moving average? or you cannot compare them? or you do not know what to do after you compared the prices? Please show your code and indicate what is the problem that you would like SOF community to help you with.